# Looping through an exploded file php error

Tags: php

I'm working on some code to loop through some output, my script seems not be waiting, anyone who can identify what my problem could be.

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q

exec("string_of_bash_commands", $in);

   foreach($in as $line) {
    $line = explode(' ', $line);
    if($line[0] > 1000) {
        echo "Critical: $line[1] has $line[0]";
             exit;  
    }

}
echo "OK";
```

The $in, receives data as below:

```
5 192.168.0.2
4 192.168.0.3
3 192.168.0.4
11428 192.168.0.5
10 192.168.0.7
```

I want to print those with over 1000, e.g `192.168.0.5`, or if all are below 1000 just print `OK`.
How can i change my code ?

Comment: Your `exec()` starts with a double quoted string, where does it end?

Comment: my apologies, yes i have fixed it. the exec output statement is fine giving the output with ip's

Comment: Can you explain more precisely the expected output of the example data above. Also is it 100 as in code or 1000 and if all are below 1000 do you still want those above 50 to be listed.

Comment: thank you i have fixed it, its 1000.

Answer (score 0):

```
// It is good practice to define some settings at the top of your code:
define('WARNING_THRESHOLD', 1000); // Place this up top in your code

$lines = explode("\n", $in);
foreach($lines as $line_number=>$line) {
    list($number, $ip) = explode(' ', $line);
    echo $ip.' '.$number.' ';
    echo $number >= WARNING_THRESHOLD ? 'WARNING' : 'OK';
}
```

> 192.168.0.2 5 OK
>   192.168.0.3 4 OK
>   192.168.0.4 3 OK
>   192.168.0.5 11428 WARNING
>   192.168.0.7 10 OK

---

Alternatively, if you want them in seperate arrays:

```
define('WARNING_THRESHOLD', 1000); // Place this up top in your code

$lines = explode("\n", $in);
foreach($lines as $line_number=>$line) {
    list($number, $ip) = explode(' ', $line);
    if( $line[0] >= WARNING_THRESHOLD ){
        $ipsGood[] = $ip;
    } else{
        $ipsBad[] = $ip;
    }
}
```

Comment: the foreach statement is not reading the lines: print $line prints the whole file , print $line[any_digit] doesnt print anything

Comment: I've added an explode on newline